# High level design or software for orthopedic surgeon software (metal rod for hip fractures)

Tags: image-processing, modeling

I am a software engineer on a large consumer Android product. I was chatting with my friend who is an orthopedic surgeon about a software idea. You can see the conversation below. The idea is to give realtime feedback to surgeons on the direction (in two or three dimensions) of a metal rod that is about to be inserted for a hip fracture. Right now the current state is trial-and-error, so getting rid of that would be a huge victory.

Does anyone have ideas on decomposing this idea in terms of software? I am an Android engineer so this way outside my expertise. My initial idea on systems needed:

- Library or tool to digitize incoming x-ray data into a 2D or 3D model of the bone and the device inserting the nail
- Library to identify the bone and the medical device in the x-ray images
- Library projecting the tip of the nail or nail insertion device into space forward into space
- UI layer that surfaces the combination of the previous two for surgeons to view real-time in the operating room

Some things that would make this (a lot?) easier, but may or may not be possible:

- Adding a sensor to the tip of the nail insertion device to track its location in 2 or 3 dimensions

Note: [here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlezIoQPxwg&t=9s) mentioned in the screenshots

[image: part one]
[image: part two]
[image: part three]
[image: part four]
[image: part five]